# Operations with Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe with the date and time column in it. I want to take the difference of the time of two consecutive timestamps and create a new column as a trip. If the difference is greater than 5 hrs it should add 1 or else it should remain the same. For the 1st timestamp, trip value can be taken as 1.

This is how dataframe looks like:

```
+---+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+
|   |           Comment                 |       Timestamp         |
+---+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  02:48:00  | 
| 2 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  03:20:00  |  
| 3 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  08:23:00  |  
| 4 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  09:48:00  |  
| 5 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  22:32:00  |           
+---+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+---+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
|   |           Comment                 |       Timestamp         |  Trip   |
+---+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 1 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  02:48:00  |   1     |
| 2 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  03:20:00  |   1     |
| 3 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  08:23:00  |   2     |
| 4 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  09:48:00  |   2     |
| 5 |             -----                 |   25-05-2019  22:32:00  |   3     |  
+---+-----------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.diff()` to compute time differences, compare those to `5:00:00`,  and `cumsum()`:

```
df['Trip'] = df.Timestamp.diff().gt('5:00:00').cumsum().add(1)
```

Output:

```
            Timestamp  Trip
0 2019-05-25 02:48:00     1
1 2019-05-25 03:20:00     1
2 2019-05-25 08:23:00     2
3 2019-05-25 09:48:00     2
4 2019-05-25 22:32:00     3
```